# Angular Routing: How to render child on new page

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

I am attempting to load my child component (BasicStatControlComponent) on a new page when I click on a button (on match-controls.component.html). However, instead of rendering BasicStatControlComponent on a new page, it populates it directly below my buttons in match-controls.component.html. How would I go about doing this? Thanks

I believe it's due to the location of the router-outlet, but I'm not really sure on how else to go about it?

I thought my issue was that since `app.component.html` has `router-outlet` already then all I would need to do is remove `router-outlet` from match-controls.component.html. However, after removing `router-outlet` from `match-controls.component.html` clicking the button yields nothing when it should've rendered `basic-stat-control.component.html`. No errors via console

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'display-runner', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'display-runner',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./display-runner/display-runner.module').then(
        m => m.DisplayRunnerModule
      )
  },
  {
    path:'match-controls',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./match-controls/match-controls.module').then(
        m => m.MatchControlsModule
      )
  }
];
```

**match-controls-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '', 
    component: MatchControlsComponent,
    children:
    [
      { path: "", redirectTo: "match-controls" },
      { path: "/players-list", component: BasicStatControlComponent },
    ] 
  }
];
```

**match-controls.component.ts**

```
        <button mat-raised-button>
            <a routerLink="/players-list">
                <div class="statLabel">Stat Label</div>
                <div class="statValue">Stat Value</div>
            </a>
        </button>
```

**basic-stat-control.component.html**

```
<h2>Players List</h2>
<div class="teamStyle">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let player of homeTeams.roster">
            <mat-slide-toggle>{{player.firstName + ' ' + player.lastName}}</mat-slide-toggle>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**match-controls.component.html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
        <h2>Home</h2>
        <button mat-raised-button> <!-- implement ngFor: let statItem of statSchema-->
            <a routerLink="/match-controls/players-list">
                <div class="statLabel">Stat Label</div>
                <div class="statValue">Stat Value</div>
            </a>
        </button>

        <button mat-raised-button>
            <div class="statLabel">Attempts Label</div>
            <div class="statValue">Attempts Value</div>
        </button>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <h2>Guest</h2>
        <button mat-raised-button>
            <div class="statLabel">Stat Label</div>
            <div class="statValue">Stat Value</div>
        </button>

        <button mat-raised-button>
            <div class="statLabel">Attempts Label</div>
            <div class="statValue">Attempts Value</div>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.html**

```
 <mat-sidenav-content>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
```

Comment: Try routerLink="/match-controls/players-list” instead of just players-list

Comment: Thanks! The error is now gone, and the URL will be /match-controls/player-list now. However, my HTML is not actually appearing. Clicking the button changes the URL to include /player-list, but the basic-stat-control.component.html is not appearing.

Comment: Actually, basic-stat-control.component.html (player-list) is rendering right below match-controls.component.html. I want this to render as it's own page. How would I go about doing this? I've edited the OP to include the changes. I believe this is due to the location of where I've included router-outlet, but I'm not sure.

Comment: will have to see your rest of the code to figure it out. DO you have multiple `router-outlet`s in app.component?

Comment: app.component.html has ```router-outlet``` & match-controls.component.html has ```router-outlet``` as well

Answer (score 0):

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '', 
    component: MatchControlsComponent,
    children:
    [
      { path: "", redirectTo: "match-controls" },
      { path: "players-list", component: BasicStatControlComponent },
    ] 
  }
];
```

The path must be written without the `/` i.e `players-list`

You have written `/players-list` instead of `players-list`